# How to Display PHP Result DATA in table

Tags: php

Step-1: Here is the function which return the resultset

```
public function getLogById($reg_id) {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tracking_log WHERE registration_id = ? LIMIT 5");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $reg_id);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {

            $result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all();
            $stmt->close();
            return $result;
        }
        else {

            return false;
        }


    }
```

Step-2: Here I am calling that function

```
if(isset($_SESSION['registration_id'])){

    $id = $_SESSION['registration_id'];

    $result = $logs->getLogById($id);

    echo "<table>";

    foreach($tracking_result as $result)
                      {
                          foreach($result as $key => $value)

                          {
                              //echo "<li>$key : $value</li>";
                              echo "<tr class=\"active\" role=\"row\">";
                              echo "<td>Here I want to Display colum-1 of my DB-Table</td>";
                              echo "<td>"Here I want to Display colum-3 of my DB-Table"</td>";
                              echo "<td>Here I want to Display colum-4 of my DB-Table</td>";
                              echo "</tr>";

                          }
                      }
    echo "<\table>";
}
```

when I `print_r($result);` it shows my result like this

```
1

35124

2017-04-12 00:00:00

30.102261

-81.711777

2

35124

2017-04-10 00:00:00

30.102261

-81.711457

3

35124

2017-04-11 00:00:00

30.063936

-81.711307

4

35124

2017-04-12 00:00:00

30.102451

-81.711957

5

35124

2017-08-12 00:00:00

30.102261

-81.795777
```

please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Fix what issue in what way? What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: Where are you declaring the actually table tags?

Comment: I want the out put in table all(5) records from my table in five rows of  html table . thats it. problem is to format the result set into html table which is what I want simply. I am newbie by the way. Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one foreach loop. And you must iterate over your db `$result`.

Depending on your fetching style you can access your columns using `$row['some_column_name']` or `$row[0]` within an foreach loop.

```
foreach($result as $row) {

    echo "<tr class=\"active\" role=\"row\">";
    echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";
    echo "</tr";

}
```

Comment: also his loop over `$tracking_result` would make it really bad, because we can't see what is it... Maybe `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks you very much @Yolo this is what I was looking for hwo to display data in table...foreach($result as $row) {

    echo "<tr class=\"active\" role=\"row\">";
    echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";
    echo "</tr";

}

Answer (score 0):

I can see some precipitations over here. The first thing I didn't understand why you put that is your loop over `$tracking_result`. The second thing is that wrong String `"<td>"Here I want to Display colum-3 of my DB-Table"</td>"`.

Whatever, the first thing you need to do is make an empty HTML sample without any PHP interaction just to look what you want to achieve. For example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
    <tr/>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1 Value 1</td>
        <td>Row 1 Value 2</td>
        <td>Row 1 Value 3</td>
    <tr/>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2 Value 1</td>
        <td>Row 2 Value 2</td>
        <td>Row 2 Value 3</td>
    <tr/>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 3 Value 1</td>
        <td>Row 3 Value 2</td>
        <td>Row 3 Value 3</td>
    <tr/>
</table>
```

That's a simple HTML table. If you want populate it with known data and known headers, you just need to focus on your rows like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
    <tr/>
    <?php foreach($results as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['value1']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['value2']; ?></</td>
        <td><?php echo $row['value3']; ?></</td>
    <tr/>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

But if you want to populate it with unkown data or headers, then we'll start something more complex. Respecting this rule you can achieve that:

## The variable $result must be an String indexed Array.

This means we can get our values Keys as our readable headers. There's an helpful PHP function to help us: [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php). With that we can get those headers as a new array. Cool, right? But it only Works if we have at least one row in `$results`. If it's just an empty array, we got nothing. So we will need to check it before start.

```
<?php
    $isEmpty = empty($results);
    if($isEmpty) {
        echo "I'm sorry, we got nothing. :(";
    } else {
        $headers = array_keys($results[0]); // I'm assuming that all of them have the same indexes.
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($headers as $header) { ?>
        <th><?php echo $header; ?></th>
        <?php } ?>
    <tr/>
    <?php foreach($results as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($headers as $header) { ?>
        <td><?php echo $row[$header]; ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
    <tr/>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
<?php
    }
?>
```

I really don't recommend to use something so generic, but that's it.

Comment: Thank you too @Kiko Garcia... your also helped me with different logic I got/learned a new technique by your logic.thanks